# Use Custom Fonts in Phoenix

Tags: fonts, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use a Custom Font in my Phoenix Application. I've placed them in the `priv/static/fonts` directory, and properly created and loaded the css file in `web/templates/layout/app.html.eex` template but they're not being served by the Phoenix Server.

```
/Users/Psycho/code/elixir/my_app/
▾ priv/
  ▸ repo/
  ▾ static/
    ▸ css/
    ▾ fonts/
      ▾ walsheim/
          gt-walsheim-light-web.svg
          gt-walsheim-light-web.eot
          gt-walsheim-light-web.ttf
          gt-walsheim-light-web.woff
```

The css file for sourcing the font:

```
// my_app/priv/css/fonts.css

@font-face {
    font-family: "Walsheim";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src:
        url("/fonts/walsheim/gt-walsheim-light-web.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("/fonts/walsheim/gt-walsheim-light-web.woff") format("woff"),
        url("/fonts/walsheim/gt-walsheim-light-web.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("/fonts/walsheim/gt-walsheim-light-web.svg#Walsheim") format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, found the solution.

It looks like you have to tell `phoenix` which directories to serve for static files. I went in to my `my_app/lib/my_app/endpoint.ex` file and updated the `Plug.Static` plug to serve the `fonts` folder as well:

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app

  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css images js fonts favicon.ico robots.txt)

  # Other Stuff ...
end
```

---

*Source: [PhoenixTalk - Serving static assets in a Sub-Folder other than the defaults](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phoenix-talk/jOKj8Myy5nc/Fj2Dhl_hGJMJ)*

Comment: Perfect answer. I will change Phoenix to include fonts by default.

Comment: For the record if you put fonts in `web/static/assets/fonts`, your fonts automatically get copied to `priv/static/fonts/` by brunch